# Regex where the delimiter appears in the strings at variable rates or not at all

Tags: python, regex

I am writing some regular expressions and for the most part they work, but I've hit a problem I've never encountered before. I have 3 group items I want to collect. For the most part, these repeat, but that's not always a guarantee. Also a variation of the " - " delimiter will not always be present. It could appear between 0 and 3 times which is why I'm thinking this might not be possible.

The ideal outcome for the text below would be

Group 1: AIT/CAL/DSN/GR/HDIL/SDL - U 1 Inch

Group 2: AIT/CAL/DSN/GR/HDIL/SDL - U 1 Inch

Group 3: 0

Group 3 is the count of Images which I can easily grab.

The text on the left is group one and in this case it's divided by a **" - "**. I found a few cases where **" - "** exists in my string. My thought is that if I could total up how many **" - "** there are and take the middle as the break, I could do it, but I have no idea how to accomplish that.

This is the expression I was using with quite a bit of success before hitting this use case with single spaces between the values due to the column limit of the output. In 95% of cases, there were at least 2 or more spaces dividing the "-" so it would look like: `"  -  "`

```
^GROUP:\s*(.*)\s{2,}-\s(.*)\s{2,}(\d*).*
```

Another approach I could take here would be to capture everything between GROUP: and X Images, then trim the white space on either side and find the number of occurrences of **" - "**. If that number were 5, I'd split it on the 3rd occurrence and have my values, but I'm just curious if regular expressions has a way to handle this.

```
GROUP:   AIT/CAL/DSN/GR/HDIL/SDL - U 1 Inch - AIT/CAL/DSN/GR/HDIL/SDL - U 1 Inch       0 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CAL/DSN/GR/HDIL/SDL - U 5 Inch - AIT/CAL/DSN/GR/HDIL/SDL - U 5 Inch       0 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - H 10 Inch - AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - H 10 Inch       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - H 10 Inch_1 - AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - H 10 Inch_1       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - H 5 Inch - AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - H 5 Inch       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - R 5 Inch - AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - R 5 Inch       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - U 2 Inch - AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - U 2 Inch       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - U 5 Inch - AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - U 5 Inch       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - U 5 Inch_1 - AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - U 5 Inch_1       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - U 5 Inch_2 - AIT/CNT/DIL/FDC/GR/HSL/SFL - U 5 Inch_2       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/FDC/GR/HSL/LDT - H 10 Inch - AIT/CNT/FDC/GR/HSL/LDT - H 10 Inch       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/FDC/GR/HSL/LDT - U 1 Inch - AIT/CNT/FDC/GR/HSL/LDT - U 1 Inch       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/FDC/GR/HSL/LDT - U 2 Inch - AIT/CNT/FDC/GR/HSL/LDT - U 2 Inch       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/FDC/GR/HSL/LDT - U 5 Inch - AIT/CNT/FDC/GR/HSL/LDT - U 5 Inch       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/FDC/GR/IL/LDT - U 5 Inch - AIT/CNT/FDC/GR/IL/LDT - U 5 Inch       0 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/GR/HSL/LDT - H 10 Inch_1 - AIT/CNT/GR/HSL/LDT - H 10 Inch_1       1 Images
GROUP:   AIT/CNT/GR/HSL/LDT/PI - D 5 Inch - AIT/CNT/GR/HSL/LDT/PI - D 5 Inch       1 Images
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your two first capture group have a pattern like `AIT/CNT/GR/HSL/LDT/PI - D 5 Inch` or `AIT/CNT/GR/HSL/LDT - H 10 Inch_1`. Which starts with space, contains `Inch` or `Inch_[digit]` at the end and follow by a space, may contains `-` or multiple spaces

```
^GROUP: +(\w.*?Inch(?:_\d*)?) +-? *(\w.*?Inch(?:_\d*)?) +(\d+) Images
```

Demo: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9hfhJs/1)

- `^GROUP: +`: Start with `GROUP:` and followed by at least one space
- `(\w.*?Inch(?:_\d*)?)`: First capture group, I add a `\w` at first place to assure that will start match a word character, then follow by any thing but non greedy `.*?`. And it ends with `Inch`, that have optional non capture group `(?:_\d*)?` to match case `Inch_1` or `Inch_12`
- `+-? *`: The delimiter part, contains at least one space  `+`, may followed by a `-` and one or many space  `*`
- `(\w.*?Inch(?:_\d*)?)`: second capture group, the same pattern at the first.
- `+`: second delimiter part, match one or many spaces
- `(\d+) Images`: third capture group `(\d+)` capture one or many digits, followed by  `Images`

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe rely on the fact that a group always starts with letters and then a slash, like `AIT/`, which you could match with `\S+\/`. If that is a consistent pattern, you could require that for the second group and do this:

```
^GROUP:\s*(.*?)[-\s]+(\S+\/.*?)[-\s]+(\d+)\s+Images
```